# possibilities for fast dynamic code execution in Python

Tags: python, scripting, abstract-syntax-tree, jit, vm-implementation

I have some code available in some form of AST and I would like to execute it.

I can think of several ways to do this, e.g.:

- Just straight-forwardly interpret it.
- Translate it into a Python AST (the `ast` module) and

  - Python-`compile` that or
  - Python-`eval` that.
- Translate it into Python source code (e.g. a pure string) and

  - Python-`compile` that or
  - Python-`eval` that.
- Translate it in some form of low level code and write a simple VM in Python which runs that.

I guess I would get the fasted execution by translating it into a Python AST, `compile` that and run that. Esp. when using PyPy, I might even get improvements by PyPys JIT compiling optimizations (I hope I do, do I?).

Can you think of other possibilities? Can you give suggestions on what might be the best way?

Comment: Why would you manually "translating it into a Python AST, compile that and run that"?  Python does that internally for you.  Why not just "straight-forwardly interpret it" and leave all the work to the already very well optimized Python?

Comment: @S.Lott: The code is not Python code.

Comment: "The code is not Python code"? Where does it say that in the question?

Comment: @S.Lott: the question just says "some form as AST", so it's not necessarily Python.

Comment: @larsmans: That kind of deduction is clever, but should not be required.  The question should be complete.

Comment: @S.Lott It's pretty clear from the question...

Comment: @Bradley Swain: Really? How -- precisely -- is "some form of AST" not Python code?  It sure sounds like Python.  The tag says Python.  What is the "clear" indicator that this is not Python?  Please don't claim that it's an obvious deduction.  My point is this: some of us don't trust deductions because we've seen one or two really bad questions on Stack Overflow before.

Comment: @S.Lott: I've seen my share of bad questions too, but I'm not disillusioned enough (yet) to assume OP misses such an obvious solution. The question states he's thinking about translating his AST into Python code or AST, so I too think it's pretty obvious that the code at hand it not Python.

Comment: @delnan: A clever deduction based on stuff not stated in the question.  It seems so simple a request: Make the question complete.  Yet, three people have told me now that making fanciful deductions is somehow acceptable.  I apologize for seeking clarity.

Comment: @S.Lott: No, you are not asked to make a clever deduction. You are asked to make one very simple deduction. You could *also* ask for clarification, but I don't see how the question could be taken with certainty as "I have Python code, how do I interpret it?". If you're demanding clarity, great, then demand clarity instead of guessing (that's what you did by assuming the AST in question is a Python AST).

Comment: @delnan:  Ah.  Good point.  Your deduction is sound, but mine is faulty.  That makes sense.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possibility: translate the AST directly to Python byte code and execute that. This is like your last idea except using the existing Python VM.

It is not a *great* possibility because it could be a lot of work and Python `compile` would probably do a better job except in rather peculiar cases, but I'm just throwing it out there.

Comment: No, this is a rather bad possibility, as the bytecode format is propably not set in stone across versions and/or implementation. Plus, translating to something as low-level as bytecode may be (if the source language is somewhat close to Python) harder than translating to a high-level language like Python, and also less supported.

Comment: Good caveats. The bytecode does change in some Python versions, but fortunately there's `dis.opmap[]` for insulating yourself from that. The main issue is that it's probably more work than translating to Python source or AST.

Comment: Also, when running in PyPy and using PyPys `compile` on a Python AST, I probably get much better performance when running that as when running (i.e. interpreting) the Python bytecode with PyPy, don't I?

Comment: I'm pretty sure PyPy's JIT compiler operates on Python bytecode, so it shouldn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility: translate to [Cython](http://cython.org) code, write out to a file, compile with Cython then a C compiler with optimization turned on, load the resulting module and execute it.

If the code has type annotations that can be translated to Cython/C types, this can be blazing fast. Watch out, though, as Cython is in beta and still a bit rough around the edges. Also, this solution only works for CPython.

Comment: Ah, also a nice idea. The only problem which will probably keep me from considering this is that this is not a pure Python solution anymore. I should have written that in my question that I am searching for such. Anyway, if that wouldn't be an issue, this solution might be quite fast. Although I could maybe also just output C code and use GCC/LLVM. Or I could generate LLVM bytecode.